# How to disallow the input of some punctuations

Tags: c#, keypress

I have a textbox, in Windows Form, for the input from a user. I want him to allow some punctuations but disallow others. How can I fix that? I have the next code:

```
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) &&
            !char.IsLetter(e.KeyChar) &&
            !char.IsPunctuation(e.KeyChar) &&
            !char.IsWhiteSpace(e.KeyChar))
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to approach this is to look at the string they inputted as an array of chars:

```
char[] strarray = userinput.ToCharArray();
```

And then just create an if statement to look for the punctuation for example:

```
if(strarray.Contains(' the punctuation you don't want')){
 // provide user input to tell the user to input a new string and reset the text box

   }
```

Hope that Helps

Comment: I was thinking about something like: if (char == "#"){e.Handled = true;}